# Use tasks and ContinueWith to implement scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, task, scheduler

I'm trying to write my own scheduler; the rationale behind it is that all the submitted actions will be executed in order, according to a delay. For example, if at time `0` I schedule action `A` with delay `5` and at time `1` I schedule action `B` with delay `2`, then `B` should be executed first at time `3` and `A` should be executed second, at time `5`.

Basically, what I am trying to do is something like:

```
public class MyScheduler
{
    Task _task = new Task(() => { });

    public MyScheduler()
    {     
        _task.Start();
    }

    public void Schedule(Action action, long delay)
    {
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromTicks(delay)).ContinueWith(_ =>
            lock(_task) {
                _task = _task.ContinueWith(task => action())
            }
        );
    }

}
```

A relevant test for this code would be:

```
 var waiter = new Waiter(3);
 int _count = 0;
 mysched = new MyScheduler();
 mysched.Schedule(() => { _count++; waiter.Signal(); });
 mysched.Schedule(() => { Task.Delay(100).Wait(); _count *= 3; waiter.Signal(); });
 mysched.Schedule(() => { _count++; waiter.Signal(); });

 waiter.Await();
 Assert.AreEqual(4, _count);
```

In the above code, `Waiter` is a class with an internal variable initialized in the constructor; the `Signal` method decrements that internal variable and the `Await` method loops (and sleeps 10 ms on each iteration) until the internal variable is less than or equal to zero.

The aim of the test is to show that the scheduled actions have been performed in order.

Most of the times this is true and the test passes, but on few occasions the resulting value for `_count` is `2` instead of `4`. I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out why this happens, but I can't seem to figure it out and my lack of experience with C# is not helping either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `Schedule(Action action, long delay)` has a *non-optional* argument `delay`, why do you not specify it when you call `mysched.Schedule`? Show the actual code, including `Waiter`.

Answer (score 4):

For one thing, `_count` is not synchronized for access from different threads.

I recommend that you not use `ContinueWith` at all; it is a very low-level method and is very easy to get the details wrong (for example, the default scheduler is `TaskScheduler.Current`, which is almost never what you want). Your general logic code should use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`.

Regarding the scheduler, these days it is almost impossible to make a good use case for developing your own. There are better ones available that are developed by geniuses and extremely well-tested. Consider Reactive Extensions: they provide several schedulers, and they all [support scheduling](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#FutureScheduling).

Comment: +1 for suggesting the Reactive Framework schedulers. They are particularly good.